# Reverting swapping CTRL and CAPS key is not persistent

Tags: keyboard, customization, system-settings

More than a year ago, I swapped the locations of <kbd>Control</kbd> and <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> keys for better ergonomy.

However, I have recently come to reconsider the choice and would like to return to the former systems with the keys in their ordinary places.

The choice seem no longer be present in normal System settings of Ubuntu 14.04, so I went on to use *Ubuntu Tweak Tool*. The changes took effect in the current session but reverted after reboot

Adding `setxkbdmap -option` to `.profile` did not solve the problem either because something seems to override this setting.

What would be the best way to get back the default keyboard behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to reset the behavior:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
```

and remove the `setxkbdmap`-thing in your `.profile`

Comment: The problem seems to recur after a new login. I would like to restore the defaults permanently without having to type the above command again at each time that I log to my computer.

Comment: What are the different setup files that can affect the keyboard behavior? Knowing this would probably lead me to the solution of the problem. As it is, I need to run "setxkbmap -option" and "xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap" at each startup, which is quite frustrating. If I put these in the list of startup applications, something overrides the changes.